# Nagios plugin quits when encountering the bc command-- how to diagnose?

Tags: bash, nagios

I've written a nagios plugin using the bash scripting language.  When I run this script by hand it works with no issue.  Putting it into a nagios plugin however, using the same parameters, leads to heartburn.

The key line involves the `bc` command.  The line in my script reads like this:

`total_percentage=$(bc <<<"scale=2;($numerator_count/$denominator_count)*100")`

if I run the script by hand all is well and `total_percentage` is calculated correctly and the script moves on.

Nagios apparently just stops cold when it runs that line.  I'm not sure how to debug this, the nagios log doesn't reveal much.  Are there extra flags I can set when starting the service that might help?  Would anyone know what might be wrong with the line above when running under nagios?

Comment: Any chance that the bc command isn't in your search path? Replacing it with the full path would quickly eliminate that.

Comment: @AndrewB it's added via a puppet module, but I'll try full-pathing it as well to eliminate the possibility and post back here.

Comment: You must assume Nagios runs with no ENV, and use 'env -i' when testing manually to simulate this.

Comment: I looked and bc is installed in /usr/bin, so it's most likely available.  I full-pathed the command to /usr/bin/bc just to play it safe and again, it worked fine on the command line but not as a nagios plugin.

Comment: Some more info.  Using the `env -i` revealed an error on the line I posted above.  'Syntax error: redirection unexpected'  Something to do with the '<<<' no doubt, but not sure what it would be?

Comment: Did you defined an hash bang line in your script ? `!#/bin/bash` What is your Linux flavour ?

Comment: @krisFR Yes, !#/bin/bash is at the top of the script.  We're running Ubuntu 12.04 on the box.

Comment: What says `echo $SHELL` within and outside your script ?

Comment: It says /bin/bash in both circumstances.

Comment: Late note-- I misspoke earlier.  I was running /bin/sh by default.  Now all is well, thanks so much for your help.
Apparently sh has trouble with the redirection I was using for bc:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462317/bash-syntax-error-redirection-unexpected